# AWS S3 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to upload images to s3 with a pre signed url generated from the aws sdk.

```
router.get('/upload-url', async(req, res) => {
    try {

        AWS.config.update({
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS,
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: 'ap-southeast-1'

        });

        const s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = { Bucket: process.env.bucket_name, Key: 'products', ContentType: 'image/jpeg' };
        s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, url) {
            if (err) {
                throw (err)
            }
            res.status(200).send({ link: url })
        })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

with the return url above, It give an error when I trying to access it

```
<Error>
<script class="__REQUESTLY__SCRIPT">(function(namespace) { window[namespace] = window[namespace] || {}; window[namespace].responseRules = {}; let open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open; XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method) { this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { if (this.readyState === 4 && window[namespace].responseRules.hasOwnProperty(this.responseURL)) { const responseRule = window[namespace].responseRules[this.responseURL]; const {response, id} = responseRule; const responseType = this.responseType; let customResponse; customResponse = response.type === 'code' ? responseRule.evaluator({ method, url: this.responseURL, requestHeaders: this.requestHeaders, requestData: this.requestData, responseType: this.responseType, response: this.response }) : response.value; Object.defineProperty(this, 'response', { get: function () { if (response.type === 'static' && responseType === 'json') { return JSON.parse(customResponse); } return customResponse; } }); if (responseType === '' || responseType === 'text') { Object.defineProperty(this, 'responseText', { get: function () { return customResponse; } }); } window.postMessage({ from: 'requestly', type: 'response_rule_applied', id }, window.location.href); } }, false); open.apply(this, arguments); }; let send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send; XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) { this.requestData = data; send.apply(this, arguments); }; let setRequestHeader = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader; XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader = function(header, value) { this.requestHeaders = this.requestHeaders || {}; this.requestHeaders[header] = value; setRequestHeader.apply(this, arguments); } })('__REQUESTLY__')</script>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>DHAWUIHDUIAWHDAWUI</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET 1594960145 /bucketname/products</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>oD2y%2Ftv04ernxLiNdMAETiebi1KXY%3D</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 35 30 34 39 36 30 31 34 35 0a 2f 64 65 76 2e 6b 6f 6c 2e 73 68 6f 70 2f 70 70 6f 64 75 63 74 73</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>11A7BD415D04AAFE7E</RequestId>
<HostId>3zFeVQCbO+LraKZ7sR1j7rgMR9KdyOEqKFGX/5QCWXMhXLBubzre7Lb1eun/zATJU/xz69mpg+o=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have been looking around other posts, but not yet found a solution.

A few suggestion that I found was:

- not to include "/" in SECRET ACCESS KEY. (my key doesn't contain slash)
- incorrect credentials (I have tested the keys with aws cli, it works)
- updating bucket permission and policy. ( I have updated to all access on the policy)

My bucket settings are as follow:

Bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1594951813323",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt15949510950",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumber>:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
Use PUT Instead of POST for the pre-sign url to upload file to S3
```

Comment: You say you are trying to "upload" an image yet according to the error message, you are using this signed URL to make a `GET` (instead of `PUT`) request.  That is expected to fail because the request does not match the signature.

Comment: Your ``Bucket Policy`` worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Yes. using `PUT` solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by recreating the key pair. As it turned out, my secret key started with an equals '=' sign. Not only did that mess with the downloaded CSV, but my guess is that is messed with the signature generation parsing software. Re-generating the key pair made the system work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the s3 bucket policy side, which is maintained by our backend team. But I was able to upload files to our public-asset bucket using both `post` and `put` method.

#### POST

**Generate presigned URL**

```
response = s3.generate_presigned_post(Bucket=BUCKET,
                                        Key=KEY,
                                        ExpiresIn=3600)
```

**Upload file using presigned URL**

```
signed_url_post = response['url']
data = response['fields']
key = response['key']

file_path = [YOUR_FILE_PATH]
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (file_path, f)}
    http_response = requests.post(url=signed_url_post, data=data, files=files)
```

#### PUT

**Generate presigned URL**

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                             ExpiresIn=3600,
                             Params={"Bucket": BUCKET,
                             "Key": KEY,
                             "ContentType": "application/octet-stream"})
```

**Upload file using presigned URL**

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
with open(file_path_, 'rb') as f:
    http_response = requests.put(url=url, data=f, headers=headers)
```

Make sure to add `headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}` if you are using `put` method

Answer (score 1):

While using `Lambda functions` with `API Gateway`,
There are a few things to consider,

1. While using the pre-signed URL, check if your request method is `PUT` or `POST`. It should be **PUT**.
2. Check your `lambda function` in AWS and make sure the `ContentType` matches with your upload.
3. Make sure the `headers` you set with the request match the `params` in the lambda. function.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `signatureVersion` in your constructor:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error, I realized that the user I was using did not have the necessary permissions for S3. Adding the permissions did not work for me, so I ended up recreating a user with those permissions. The new API Key and Secret I generated worked successfully.